# ARC2 construct "raw" is not returning RDF

Tags: php, sparql, php-arc

I am using PHP's ARC2 for a construct query. I was hoping something like 
$q = "CONSTRUCT ... "
$data = $store->query($query, "raw");

Would return raw RDF, but it's returning a structured array... How can I just get a dump of the RDF?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki/Using-ARC%27s-RDF-Store) it looks like the only difference between raw and normal output is that the raw output doesn't incorporate metadata like query time

To turn this raw output into actual RDF you can serialize this structure as described in their [serialization documentation](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki/Serializing-ARC-Structures):

```
$ser = ARC2::getRDFXMLSerializer();
$rdfxml = $ser->getSerializedIndex($data);
```

*Disclaimer* The above is an adapted copy and paste from their documentation so no guarantee I got the syntax exactly right